# Setting up xlrd with Python

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm trying to get a data management program running so I can rearrange some data for the company I work for using Python. I don't really have any experience with Python, but I do with java.

http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf

I found this website that talks about using xlrd and xlwt. I ran xlrd-0.7.1.win32.exe so the api is installed. But even when I try to get the simple script running, it can't find the open_workbook function:

"Undefined variable from import: open_workbook"

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('yee.xls')
```

Can someone send me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you make sure the installer installed to the version of the Python interpreter that you're using? I would also note it appears the installer is out of date - so maybe it's better you use `easy_install` or `pip` to get the latest 0.9.x series

Comment: im using pydev as an IDE, that wouldn't matter right? Just the version of Python? And yea, I used an older version so it would have an exe to ensure it installed

Comment: what version of python and xlrd should I be using?

Comment: Then you're possibly not installing to the same python version your IDE is using

Comment: If you can go to the command line, see if your python distribution has `easy_install` or `pip` and invoke either one of them in the CMD. Then you can do `easy_install xlrd` or `pip install xlrd` to install the packages.

Comment: If you've named a file `xlrd.py` higher up on your PYTHONPATH, you might get an error like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('foo.xls')
```